# Making JFrame fade away within 20 Sec if there is no mouse event

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fadeout

Need help in below code,I am using `JFrame` as popup to show notification, so when any new notification pops up, it should slowly pop away and then disappear in 20 secs if there is no mouse event.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new Timer(5000,new ActionListner(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                alpha+=increment;
                if(alpha>=225){
                    alpha=225;
                    increment=-increment;
                }
                if(alpha<=0){
                    alpha=0;
                    increment=-increment;
                }
                frame.setForeground(new color(0,0,0,alpha));
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
frame.setForeground(new color(0,0,0,alpha));
```

Try using

```
frame.setBackground(new color(0,0,0,alpha));
```

Depending on what you have on the frame, you'll need to use a `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` to monitor mouse events. You can then use another `Timer` which would be reset very time a mouse event occurred.

Once this `Timer` finally triggers, you would start the fade cycle...

Take a look at:

- [How to write MouseListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [How to write MouseMotionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)